# Restore SQL database - Incorrect syntax near '-'

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to restore a database with a `-` in the name. If I have no `-` in the name, the database is correctly restored.

If I put `''` around the database it still doesn't work. I'm still searching what to do but I can't find it.

```
$sqlRestoreCommand.CommandText = "RESTORE DATABASE '$databaseName' FROM DISK = '$databaseBackup' " ;
```

The following exception occurs and the code is below:

> Exception: Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near '-'.
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.".Exception.Message

```
$databaseName = "TempRpc-RC";

# Write the state for debugging purposes.
"SQL State" > sqlstatelog.txt;
$connection.State >> sqlstatelog.txt;

# Create the SQL restore command.
$sqlRestoreCommand = $connection.CreateCommand();

# Set the command text to a SQL restore command and fill in the parameters.
# With move option is needed!
$sqlRestoreCommand.CommandText = "RESTORE DATABASE $databaseName FROM DISK = '$databaseBackup' " ;
$sqlRestoreCommand.CommandText += "WITH FILE = 1, ";
$sqlRestoreCommand.CommandText += "MOVE N'$databaseName" + "'" + " TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Data\$databaseName" + "_Data.mdf', ";
$sqlRestoreCommand.CommandText += "MOVE N'$databaseName" + "_log'" +" TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Data\$databaseName" +"_Log.ldf'";
$sqlRestoreCommand.Connection = $connection;

# Execute the commands.
$sqlRestoreResult = $sqlRestoreCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

# Write the query
Write-Verbose $sqlRestoreCommand.CommandText;
```

Comment: You need square brackets around the database name, not single quotes (`RESTORE DATABASE [$databaseName] FROM ...`). Also, you shouldn't build your queries that way, b/c it opens your code up to SQL injection.

Comment: Okay but how should I build up my code?

Comment: Use prepared statements (or "parameterized queries" as Microsoft likes to call them).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will read in to it. Changing it to square brackets was the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

Inside the expandable PowerShell string (`"..."`) that defines the query string, replace `'$databaseName'` with `[$databaseName]`

As an aside: Unless you fully control all parts used to construct the query string, you should use [*parameters*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters) to avoid SQL injection attacks, as Ansgar advises.

---

[Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) provided the crucial pointer:

Since your database name contains a `-` character, it isn't a [*regular* identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-2017#rules-for-regular-identifiers), so it must be quoted / delimited, i.e., it must be specified as a *delimited identifier*.
Additionally, identifiers that conflict with [*reserved keywords*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) must be specified as delimited identifiers too.

A delimited identifier is one enclosed in either `[...]` or `"..."`; by contrast, `'...'` is *not* supported, which explains your symptoms.

<sup>Note: `[...]` is SQL Server-specific, but is *always* supported there, whereas the standard `"..."` is only supported when `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` is in effect in T-SQL, which is true by default, however - except in certain situations, such as when using `sqlcmd.exe` without `-l`.</sup>